# What is the solution of $x^3+y^3+z^3=429$ in integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, catalan-numbers

I have tried to solve  $x^3+y^3+z^3=429$  using mathematica (Reduce[x^3+y^3+z^3 == 429 && x > 0 && y > 0,&& z > 0,  {x, y,z}, Integers] ) and [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+in+integers+x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%3D429) I can't come up to the solution of $x^3+y^3+z^3=429$ however $429$ mod $9$ neither $5$ or $4$ mod $9$  and in the same time is not classified as unsolved as montioned in linked papers  which are montioned in  [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways), , Probably I have missed somethings in my Code , ,I was interested to this number to know more about Catalan numbers representation as sum of three cubic.

Comment: You could trivially solve this by exhaustive search. If each is required to be positive then you’ll need $ x,y,z \le 7$. By symmetry, you could further assume without loss of generality that $x\le y\le z$ which reduces the search space.

Comment: I believe you need to delete the positive constraint in your Mathematica code.

Comment: @User8128 Although the search will turn out to be short in *some* cases, this is not true in general. In some cases, the search is [reportedly](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf) not trivial.

Comment: $182^3+284^3-307^3=429$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known integer solutions as of Apirl 2007${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.
$$\begin{align}
429 &= 284^3 + 182^3 +(-307)^3\\
    &= 644^3 + 533^3 + (-748)^3\\
    &= 871146950^3 + 15204917^3 + (-871148494)^3
\end{align}$$

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - 
  *List of solutions of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = n$ for $n < 1000$
  neither a cube nor twice a cube*. 
  Andreas-Stephan Elsenhans and Joerg Jahnel, April 2007 (
  an online copy of the list can be found [here](https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/jahnel/Arbeiten/Liste/threecubes_20070419.txt)).

Comment: Thanks for bringing sense into this thread!

Comment: Nice! Needs a broader search I guess.

Comment: Let me also add this link here (especially that  nown=42 also has a solution). https://math.mit.edu/~drew/Waterloo2019.pdf

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help (This way you can search a range). I don't yet see integer triplets satisfying $429$. The closest seen is $432$ (if $0$ can be included $6^3+6^3+0^3=432$). For strictly positive integer triplets the nearest number is 433 ($433=6^3+6^3+1^3$).

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^3 + z^3
sol = Maximize[{f[x, y, z], 429 <= f[x, y, z] <= 432, x >= 0 , y >= 0,
z >= 0}, {x, y, z} \[Element] Integers]
```

Also, if you wish to stretch to -ve integers that is doable. For example,

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^3 + z^3
sol = Maximize[{f[x, y, z], 420 <= f[x, y, z] <= 430, 10 >= x >= -10 ,
10 >= y >= -10, 10 >= z >= -10}, {x, y, z} \[Element] Integers]
```

Will result in
     {424, {x -> -8, y -> -4, z -> 10}}

Some useful links (about recent progress): https://math.mit.edu/~drew/Waterloo2019.pdf
http://news.mit.edu/2019/answer-life-universe-and-everything-sum-three-cubes-mathematics-0910

Comment: And the closest to 627 is 622=7^3+7^3-4^3

Comment: if the solution really exist in your given range , I think we should  retire wolfram alpha

Comment: I checked with Mathematica. It works.